# The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

Here is my code:

```
function DoAddAllCartItems(spaceID, colorID, themeID, width) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'myservice.svc/AddAllCartItems',
            data: "{spaceID: " + "'" + spaceID + "'" + ", colorID: " + "'" + colorID + "'" + ", themeID: " + "'" + themeID + "'" + ", width: " + "'" + width + "'" + "}",
            contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "xml",
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });



    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string AddAllCartItems(int spaceID, int colorID, int themeID, int width);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to provide more information. For a start, host the web service in IIS and hook up Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to have a look at what is coming back from the web service.

My first guess would be that your AddAllCartItems method is throwing an exception.  Other than that, possibly an issue with stringifying the integer parameters?

Comment: I had an issue with the stringify. I used JSON.stringify and it worked.